# UITableView Overlaying cells on top of each other

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I thought my table was fine until I changed the backgrounds to be a little transparent, which showed previous cells underneath new dequeued cells.  This is the code in my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. I took out redundant label set up, which are all the same as `timeLabel`.

```
static NSString* cellIdentifer = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifer];

if (!cell)
{
    cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifer];
}

int offset = 5;
int rowHeight = 120;
UIView* cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(offset, offset, 320 - offset * 2, rowHeight - offset * 2)];

cellView.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? [UIColor colorWithWhite: 1.0 alpha: .8 ] : [UIColor colorWithWhite: .3 alpha: .8];

int padding = 5;

int x1 = 5;
int x2 = CGRectGetWidth(cellView.frame) / 3;
int x3 = x2 * 2;

int y1 = 5;
int y2 = CGRectGetHeight(cellView.frame) / 2 + padding;

int width = CGRectGetWidth(cellView.frame) / 3 - padding;
int sHeight = CGRectGetHeight(cellView.frame) / 2 - padding;
int bHeight = CGRectGetHeight(cellView.frame) - padding;

CGRect cell1 = CGRectMake(x1, y1, width, sHeight);

int row = indexPath.row;// - 1;

UILabel* timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: cell1];
timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
timeLabel.text = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex: row] objectForKey: @"time"];
[cellView addSubview: timeLabel];


[cell.contentView addSubview: cellView];
```

[image: Here's a screenshot of what's happening]

Comment: What is the height of your cell?

Comment: 120. Set in the XIB and the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` call

Comment: Can you attach image of your screen shot

Comment: @Chris I put you code in my method and it's giving me good behaviour.
Are you sure you are retuning 120 from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: @BestCoder I attached a screenshot.. Sorry it's massive.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Yes, I'm return 120 from that method

Comment: Do not use deque method and make cell each time without using any identifier. Because As I am seeing your cells are overlapping.

Comment: cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: nil];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating new `UIView` and `UILabel` even if the cell is reused which results showing old one below your new one.

Do like this

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifer];

if (!cell)
{
    cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifer];

    int offset = 5;
    int rowHeight = 120;
    UIView* cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(offset, offset, 320 - offset * 2, rowHeight - offset * 2)];
    cellView.tag = 200;
    cellView.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? [UIColor colorWithWhite: 1.0 alpha: .8 ] : [UIColor colorWithWhite: .3 alpha: .8];

    int padding = 5;

    int x1 = 5;
    int x2 = CGRectGetWidth(cellView.frame) / 3;
    int x3 = x2 * 2;

    int y1 = 5;
    int y2 = CGRectGetHeight(cellView.frame) / 2 + padding;

    int width = CGRectGetWidth(cellView.frame) / 3 - padding;
    int sHeight = CGRectGetHeight(cellView.frame) / 2 - padding;
    int bHeight = CGRectGetHeight(cellView.frame) - padding;

    CGRect cell1 = CGRectMake(x1, y1, width, sHeight);

    int row = indexPath.row;// - 1;
    UILabel* timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: cell1];
    timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    timeLabel.tag = 300;
    [cellView addSubview: timeLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: cellView];
}

UIView *view = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:200];
UILabel *timeLabel = (UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:300];
timeLabel.text = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex: row] objectForKey: @"time"];
```

Instead of having this messy thing I would suggest you to create a [custom `UITableViewCell`](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

Comment: Yeah you have to create custom cell for simplicity. Other wise as you subviews grows it will become more complex and less readable.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is with cell= `[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifer];`method so if you do not want to change anything then use method like this `UITableViewCell *cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: nil];`

This is not better way but you can use this. Because in this case your cell will not be reused. One better solution is that make custom cell with your choice and use it.